# xsl:fo image displays as black box in only Google chrome

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome, xslt-2.0, xsl-fo

I am creating a pdf file using xsl:fo,

Right now I am facing issue in Google chrome browser.

While generating pdf file, the image in the pdf does not display. instead of image there a black box appear.

I have type try all content-type for  xsl:fo external-graphic.

But I get black box instead of image.

I am only facing this issue in Google chrome browser only, in other browser it works fine.

Here is the code, which is i am using for displaying image in the pdf using xsl:fo

```
<fo:table-cell text-align="left" padding-left="30px" padding-bottom="10px" background-color="white">
              <fo:block>
                <fo:external-graphic content-width="100%" content-height="100%" content-type="content-type:image/jpg">
                  <xsl:attribute name="src">url(http://../images/barcode1.jpg)</xsl:attribute>
                </fo:external-graphic>
              </fo:block>
            </fo:table-cell>
```

Comment: Could be an issue with the .jpg file. Have you tried this: put the image in a Word file, save as PDF and open the PDF in Chrome. If that also results in a black box, you know the problem is in the code that reads PDF within Chrome.

Comment: Thanks @Hobbes for reply, its not a .jpg file issue, i have try all different extension image, but it not works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We do not see much of your XSLT or XSL-FO code, so this is only a guess. Try

```
<fo:external-graphic content-width="100%" content-height="100%" content-type="content-type:image/jpg">
     <xsl:attribute name="src">
        <xsl:value-of select="http://../images/barcode1.jpg"/>
     </xsl:attribute>
</fo:external-graphic>
```

and let me know if there is any change.